# List members in current file

Tags: visual-studio-2008

There is a bar at the top of source edit windows in Visual studio with two combo boxes listing types and members. Is there any shortcut to open the second combo from keyboard? I used before Visual Assist X, it had a replacement for this bar with nasty shortcuts and search functionality. This is only thing I'm missing after migrating to Resharper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with three keypresses (or use a macro) - Ctrl-F2, Tab, DownArrow.

Edit: This varies by keyboard settings: in the default settings, Ctrl-F2 is the shortcut for Window.MoveToNavigationBar: if you look that up in Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard you can find the equivalent in your keyboard settings.